# change default url routing to RESTful like url on ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to change the default routing of `ASP MVC`  (`controller/action/id`) to lets say

```
course-categories/view/1 to course-categories/1
course-categories/edit/1 to course-categories/1/edit
```

tried this one

```
context.MapRoute(
                name: "ControlPanel.CourseCategory",
                url: "controlpanel/course-categories/{id}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "CourseCategory", action = "View", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "Website.Areas.ControlPanel.Controllers" }
                );
```

course-categories/create now cant be mapped or course-categories/{action}

- is it a good idea to change the default routing?
- can I create another route to map the course-categories/{action}?
- can anyone suggest routing that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are putting the ID inside the route and making it optional with also a default value for the action, I would put a constraint on the ID to help avoid routing clashes.

```
context.MapRoute( 
    ...
    constraints: new { id = @"(\d)+" }
);
```